# Guice NullPointerExceptions

Tags: javafx-8, guice

So I am new to Guice and I am continually getting `NullPointerException`s whenever I attempt to use my Injected objects.

I at first thought it was the weird complexity of my program, but I created a very, very simple test program and I still get them. Program is below:

> Main.java

```
public class Main  extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());

        Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addtest.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p, 100, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> BillingModule.java

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Add.class).to(AddImpl.class);
    }
}
```

> Add interface

```
public interface Add {
   int add(int a, int b);
}
```

> AddImpl

```
public class AddImpl implements Add{
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

> FXML Controller

```
public class AddTestController {
    @Inject private Add add;
    public void initialize(){}
    @FXML
    private void addTestButton(){
        System.out.println(add.add(1,3));
    }
}
```

> FXML file

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="AddTestController">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addTestButton" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

As you can see it is a VERY simple program, and I still can not seem to get this to work.

My goal is to have `Add` being Injected without having to call `injector.getInstance(Add.class)`, but instead see the `@Inject` and resolve the dependency itself, which it is not doing.

I feel like I am missing a very basic understanding of why its not working, but it just hasn't revealed itself yet.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

P.S. I am using Field injection as an example here, I know its not suggested and in my actual program will not be using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guice only injects to classes created using `Injector.getInstance`. You need to create the controller using this method. You could do this by setting the `controllerFactory` of `FXMLLoader` before calling the `load` method:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("addtest.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
Parent p = loader.load();
```

Comment: This did indeed solve my problems. Even the ones I didn't ask. Thank you.